# Is Batch processing available in google geocode API

Tags: google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api, geocoder, reversegeocodelocation

I have gone through google geocode documenation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding

It says:
50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

However I didnt find any process to do batch processing(sending multiple addresses in a single call and fetch response). I have a usecase, where in I have to pass a pandas df with address params as an input to API and fetch response for 50000 records. Its a time taking process if we send each request independently.

Is there a way to apply batch processing for google geocode API

Answer (score 0):

There is no batch processing the Geocoding API; one address, one request.

To do any amount of address >1, you need to implement the batch pipeline yourself. With 50,000 entries it *will* take time anyway, at least 1,000 seconds if you manage to sustain 50 QPS.